# Отслеживание событий при закрытом приложении

Tags: java, android, kotlin

поместил broadcastReceiver в Manifest файл, однако он не срабатывает если приложение закрыто, подскажите пожалуйста что нужно добавить, чтобы событие отлавливалось ресивером даже когда приложение закрыто(API 25)

Comment: Возможно дело в том, как именно приложение закрыто. Вроде бы некоторые оболочки при смахивании приложения будут останавливать процесс, тем самым выключая все ресиверы. Попробуйте проверить работоспособность ресивера при свёрнутом приложении. И при закрытом, но на других девайсах и других версиях ОС.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб попробую, спасибо, может вы знаете, приложения типа вконтакте, инстаграм и телеграм для показа уведомлений используют broadcastReceiver или там нечто другое?

Comment: У них у всех по большей части приём уведомлений через FCM идёт. Там всё работает через гугловые службы, которые почти невозможно убить и которые игнорируют правила работы обычных служб и ресиверов.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Понял, ещё раз спасибо!)

Comment: В идеале с push-ми работать именно через FCM, Но не всегда это возможно. Если вам не особо важно время получения и показа уведомлений, то у вас при пробуждении должен ресивер отлично срабатывать. В инном же варианте, можно намутить пару костылей, для этого стоит изучить оригинальный будильник: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/

Comment: спасибо за совет!)